# Compass set .css output path to same location as .scss

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass

I have my compiled .css files in multiple, diverse directories along my app, and the Sass compiler I was previously using simply compiled the .scss files to a .css file in whatever directory they were in.

Compass seems to require a single 'output' directory that you can configure, that all of your compiled .css files go to, and it only watches a single folder.

How do you tell Compass to simply compile to the location of the .scss file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silly me (then). Compass does this as well. Just pick the highest parent folder for your project as the `sass` and `css` dirs in your `config.rb` file, and compass will recursively loop through and compile the css into sass in whatever directory it found it.

```
sass_options = {:cache_location => "./temp/.sass-cache"}
http_path = "/"
css_dir = "therootdirectory"
sass_dir = "therootdirectory"
images_dir = "therootdirectory/assets/images/sprites"
javascripts_dir = "javascripts"
```

Answer (score 1):

Compass uses a ruby config file named `config.rb`. In it a user can set various paths for assets, the style of output, as well as the path for CSS output.

Documentation on the Compass website: http://compass-style.org/help/tutorials/configuration-reference/

This is a sample of what I typically use for projects, which compiles my CSS into a different place than the SCSS. If you wanted it to be in the same place, you could use `.` as the path (a single period) which would tell it to compile into the same directory as the directory that you `watch` with the command line.

```
# Set this to the root of your project when deployed:
http_path = "/www/"
sass_dir = "sass"
images_dir = "../www/lib/cssimgages"
javascripts_dir = "../www/lib/js"
fonts_dir = "../www/lib/fonts"
css_dir = "../www/lib/css"

# You can select your preferred output style here (can be overridden via the command line):
# output_style = :expanded or :nested or :compact or :compressed
output_style = :compact
```

I do agree with some of the other comments, though. You HTTP requests should be kept as low as possible, probably only referring to one stylesheet for mobile-first styles and another for styles within media-queries. But that doesn't answer your question.